# SQL Server Real Time Data integration with different Instance

Tags: sql-server

I have got a SQL application which needs to be merged with a new CRM applicaiton.
so data coming into the source tables, then triggers push certain fields into the Staging table with a flag '0' and then CRM application job picks up from staging table and sets the flag to '1'.

same is true if the data for the same field is initiated from the CRM and needs to go into my application.

All well and good.

Now considering 100s of transactions per minute is the above solution workable.
i can think of other alternatives like

SIS 
data replication
service broker (limited knowledge) etc

Comment: different instance or just a different database in the same instance?

Comment: Have you considered putting them in the same instance? Does the data really need to be redundant?

Comment: so i have got a web based application and the CRM applicaiton both have separate schemas but some data fields needs to be integrated

Comment: And you cant move the web app DB to the CRM instance? I understand if there is some invalidation of support issue but it would be much better as you wouldn't need to use linked servers to communicate between the instances

Comment: Sorry i misunderstood your question it is the same instance but different database

Comment: I'm not sure this is answerable without more information.  100s of transactions is nothing, if they're sales records or something, a few hundred bytes each.  If each "transaction" is 10 GB of scientific data, then you have a problem.  Is the real question "are triggers the best way to handle real-time ETL across MS SQL instances on the same server?"

Comment: yes the question is about using triggers and stagging tables vs other possible solutions.